# Disabling printing options from chrome print dialog

Tags: javascript, css, printing, google-chrome-frame

I am giving a command of printing from chrome. i just want to disable no of copy option from that. I want to restrict user to change the no of copy option from dialog.
as shown in the image i want it as disabled or removed from it.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, just find your Chrome shortcut, and add "--args --disable-print-preview" to the launch command.

For example, if you've pinned Chrome to your taskbar, right-click the icon, then right-click on "Google Chrome" (near the bottom of the list), then click on properties.  In the target window, add the string above to the end.  It should now look like:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --args --disable-print-preview
```

where `<user>` is your username.  Hit apply/ok and relaunch your browser usin this shortcut (make the same adjustment to other shortcuts if necessary).